# The "overdamped" approximation: deleting the higher order term in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion

Say we have an ode of the form
$$
\epsilon \ddot{x} + a\dot{x} + b x = 0
$$
If $\epsilon$ is small enough the approximation
$$
a\dot{x} + b x = 0
$$
is often done in physics; in fact, I'm interested in the more general case
$$
\epsilon \ddot{x} + F(\dot{x},x) = 0
$$
How is the approximation rigorously justified? I imagine that somehow an expansion in terms of $\epsilon$ appears.

Comment: Strictly speaking you haven't specified what features you claim the approximation has, so as it stands "rigorously justifying" the approximation doesn't have any meaning. That said, a starting point for analyzing such an approximation would be writing $x$ in a power series in the independent variable.

Comment: I haven't, precisely because I have "seen" the approximation without any justification. In some sense, the solution of the first system converges to the solution of the second system as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, but I don't know exactly how, and that is what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this is generally done by using *regular perturbation theory*. When the small parameter is multiplying the highest order term though, as well as in some other cases, *singular perturbation theory* should be used. The topic is treated in detail on [this notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/notes/asy.pdf).